# Django migration problem with long traceback

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a strange and frustrating problem with migration that I can't figure out. I'm not experienced in debugging. The steps before `python3 manage.py makemigrations` was OK. This is the log I kept. Could you please help me?

```
ruszakmiklos@Ruszak-MacBook-Pro firm % python3 manage.py migrate       
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, stressz
Running migrations:
  Applying stressz.0050_auto_20210504_0757...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 328, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 189, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 303, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 823, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 818, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'att_v003' expected a number but got ''.
ruszakmiklos@Ruszak-MacBook-Pro firm %
```

I don't find where should I change anything with 'att_v003'

```
ValueError: Field 'att_v003' expected a number but got ''.
```

**forms.py**

```
class AttitudForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Attitud
    fields = '__all__'

    widgets = {
        'att_v001': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'custom-radio-list'}),
        'att_v002': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'custom-radio-list'}),
        'att_v003': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'custom-radio-list'}),
    }
```

For me it seems my model is good, I can't find typerror or something else.

**models.py**

```
class Attitud(models.Model):

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user_name)

class question(models.IntegerChoices):
    Nem_jellemző = 0
    Néha_jellemző = 1
    Nagyon_jellemző = 2

user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
att_v001 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "a", default='', null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
att_v002 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "b", default='', null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
att_v003 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "c", default='', null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
```

**html**

```
{% extends 'stressz/base.html' %}
{% block body%}
{% comment %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% endcomment %}

<div class="container w-75">
<div class="display-4">Helló {{ user.get_short_name}}! 
</div>

<p class="text-justify">Kérlek, hogy az alábbi kérdések esetében válaszd ki, hogy melyek a rád leginkább jellemző kijelentések. </p>
</div>

<form method = "POST">
    <div class="container w-75 bg-light rounded-3 pt-3">
        <div class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 border-right border-primary p-3">
            <h6 class="text-primary">1. Néha "felesleges" dolgokat vásárolok csupán azért, mert ez örömöt szerez nekem.</h6>
            {{ form.att_v001 }}<br>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-4  border-primary  pt-3 pl-4">
            <h6 class="text-primary">2. Néha "felesleges" dolgokat vásárolok csupán azért, mert ez örömöt szerez nekem.</h6>
            {{ form.att_v002 }}<br>
            </div>
       

            <div class="col-4 border-left border-primary pt-3 pl-4">
            <h6 class="text-primary">3. Néha "felesleges" dolgokat vásárolok csupán azért, mert ez örömöt szerez nekem.</h6>
            {{ form.att_v003 }}<br>
            </div>

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Mentés</button>
```

`{% endblock %}`

Comment: A string default (`default=''`) for an integer field? Does not make sense, yes?

Comment: I made it, but it writes the same.

Comment: You need to delete the migration file `stressz.0050_auto_20210504_0757` or edit it and remove that default from there. (If you do delete it, delete all successive migrations (0051, 0052, ...) too that you might have made, since they depend on this one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the integer column you're trying to add string value, try to remove default in models.

**Instead of this**

```
att_v003 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "c", default='', null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
```

**Use**

```
att_v003 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "c", default=0, null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)

**OR**

att_v003 = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "c", default=0, null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
```